# UIScrollView contentOffset pinned at {0, 0}

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a [project](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13PDFKit) that I am working on, and somehow managed to break functionality of a UIScrollView while trying to fix something else. I reverted the code, but the scroll view was still broken. To reach the bug, run the project, and select "Basic Viewer" in the table view. Now try to zoom and pan the visible page... It will zoom, but not scroll.

So the problem is that the scroll view's content offset is pinned to {0, 0}. (Even after zooming.) And the thing that is causing it to be pinned is not calling `setContentOffset:`. I've subclassed the UIScrollView to debug what is going on, and have figured out it is not a problem with the UIPanGestureRecognizer, that is sending the proper values to `setContentOffset:`.

The scroll view is a subview of a UICollectionViewCell. This is how it get added to the cell:

```
- (void)setPageContentView:(PDFKPageContentView *)pageContentView
{
    if (_pageContentView) {
        [self removeConstraints:[self constraints]];
        [_pageContentView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    if (pageContentView == nil) {
        return;
    }

    _pageContentView = pageContentView;
    _pageContentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.contentView addSubview:_pageContentView];

    NSMutableArray *constraints = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[content]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBaseline metrics:nil views:@{@"superview": self.contentView, @"content": _pageContentView}] mutableCopy];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[content]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:@{@"superview": self.contentView, @"content": _pageContentView}]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

And the UIScrollView subclass:

```
@implementation PDFKPageContentView
{
    PDFKPageContent *theContentView;
    PDFKPageContentThumb *theThumbView;
    UIView *theContainerView;
}

static void *PDFKPageContentViewContext = &PDFKPageContentViewContext;

static inline CGFloat ZoomScaleThatFits(CGSize target, CGSize source)
{
    CGFloat w_scale = (target.width / source.width);
    CGFloat h_scale = (target.height / source.height);
    return ((w_scale < h_scale) ? w_scale : h_scale);
}

- (void)updateMinimumMaximumZoom
{
    CGRect targetRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0, 0);
    CGFloat zoomScale = ZoomScaleThatFits(targetRect.size, theContentView.bounds.size);
    //Set the minimum and maximum zoom scales
    self.minimumZoomScale = zoomScale;
    self.maximumZoomScale = (zoomScale * ZOOM_MAXIMUM);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame fileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL page:(NSUInteger)page password:(NSString *)phrase
{
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))
    {
            self.scrollsToTop = NO;
            self.delaysContentTouches = NO;
            self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
            self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
            self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
            self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            self.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
            self.pagingEnabled = NO;
            self.bouncesZoom = YES;
            self.delegate = self;
            self.scrollEnabled = YES;
            self.clipsToBounds = YES;

            theContentView = [[PDFKPageContent alloc] initWithURL:fileURL page:page password:phrase];

            if (theContentView != nil)
            {
                    theContainerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:theContentView.bounds];
                    theContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
                    theContainerView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
                    theContainerView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                    theContainerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
                    theContainerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
                    theContainerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                    //Content size same as view size
                    self.contentSize = theContentView.bounds.size;

                    //Add the thumb view to the container view
                    theThumbView = [[PDFKPageContentThumb alloc] initWithFrame:theContentView.bounds]; // Page thumb view
                    [theContainerView addSubview:theThumbView];

                    //Add the content view to the container view
                    [theContainerView addSubview:theContentView];

                    //Add the container view to the scroll view
                    [self addSubview:theContainerView];

                    //Update the minimum and maximum zoom scales
                    [self updateMinimumMaximumZoom];

                    //Set zoom to fit page content
                    self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
            }

            [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:PDFKPageContentViewContext];

            //Tag the view with the page number
            self.tag = page;
        }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" context:PDFKPageContentViewContext];
}

- (void)showPageThumb:(NSURL *)fileURL page:(NSInteger)page password:(NSString *)phrase guid:(NSString *)guid
{
    //Page thumb size
    BOOL large = ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    CGSize size = (large ? CGSizeMake(PAGE_THUMB_LARGE, PAGE_THUMB_LARGE) : CGSizeMake(PAGE_THUMB_SMALL, PAGE_THUMB_SMALL));

    PDFKThumbRequest *request = [PDFKThumbRequest newForView:theThumbView fileURL:fileURL password:phrase guid:guid page:page size:size];

    //Request the page thumb
    UIImage *image = [[PDFKThumbCache sharedCache] thumbRequest:request priority:YES];

    // Show image from cache
    if ([image isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]]) [theThumbView showImage:image];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    //Reset the zoom on frame change.
    //Our context
    if (context == PDFKPageContentViewContext) {

        if ((object == self) && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
            CGFloat oldMinimumZoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
            //Update zoom scale limits
            [self updateMinimumMaximumZoom];

            //Old minimum
            if (self.zoomScale == oldMinimumZoomScale) {
                self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
            } else {
                // Check against minimum zoom scale
                if (self.zoomScale < self.minimumZoomScale) {
                    self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
                } else {
                    // Check against maximum zoom scale
                    if (self.zoomScale > self.maximumZoomScale) {
                        self.zoomScale = self.maximumZoomScale;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //Center the content when zoomed out
    CGSize boundsSize = self.bounds.size;
    CGRect viewFrame = theContainerView.frame;

    if (viewFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        viewFrame.origin.x = (((boundsSize.width - viewFrame.size.width) / 2.0f) + self.contentOffset.x);
    else
        viewFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;

    if (viewFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        viewFrame.origin.y = (((boundsSize.height - viewFrame.size.height) / 2.0f) + self.contentOffset.y);
    else
        viewFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;

    theContainerView.frame = viewFrame;
    theThumbView.frame = theContainerView.bounds;
    theContentView.frame = theContainerView.bounds;
}

- (id)processSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    return [theContentView processSingleTap:recognizer];
}

- (void)zoomIncrement
{    
    CGFloat zoomScale = self.zoomScale;

    if (zoomScale < self.maximumZoomScale) {
        zoomScale *= ZOOM_FACTOR; // Zoom in

        if (zoomScale > self.maximumZoomScale) {
            zoomScale = self.maximumZoomScale;
        }

        [self setZoomScale:zoomScale animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)zoomDecrement
{
    CGFloat zoomScale = self.zoomScale;

    if (zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale) {
        zoomScale /= ZOOM_FACTOR; // Zoom out

        if (zoomScale < self.minimumZoomScale) {
            zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
        }

        [self setZoomScale:zoomScale animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)zoomReset
{
    if (self.zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale) {
        self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale;
    }
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return theContainerView;
}

#pragma mark UIResponder instance methods

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; // Message superclass
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event]; // Message superclass
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event]; // Message superclass
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]; // Message superclass
}

- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    if (bounds.size.width != 0 && bounds.size.height == 0) {
        [super setBounds: bounds];
    }
}

@end
```

In the project, I have overridden `setContentOffset:`, `setContentSize:`, `setFrame:`, and `setBounds:`, of the UIScrollView to print out debug information, and all seems normal.

I'm stumped, Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me solve this.